# How do I fix 'namespace not specified' error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework

[image]

```
Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

android {
namespace 'com.example.namespace'
}

If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.
```

I am getting this error after upgrading to Android Studio Flamingo and after giving AGP Upgrade Assistant from 7.4.2 to 8.0.0.

This is for an ionic project so the namespace is already specified in the build.gradle file like so,

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    namespace 'com.example.m'
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.ionic.starter"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        aaptOptions {
             // Files and dirs to omit from the packaged assets dir, modified to accommodate modern web apps.
             // Default: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/282e181b58cf72b6ca770dc7ca5f91f135444502/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp#61
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:$androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:$coreSplashScreenVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
    implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
    def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
    if (servicesJSON.text) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.info("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

I tried adding the namespace to AndroidManifest.xml as a package name and as a namespace attribute in the build.gradle also. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Same thing happens to me. Please help.

Comment: I'm just upgrading my Ionic app to Capacitor 5 and have hit this issue.  Did you solve it?

Comment: I think the solution was to add the namespace in all modules including the plugins. We didn't do it because of time constraints. We just downgraded the Gradle version for now.

Comment: I went to File >> Project Structure >> Gradle Plugin and I reverted to an older version of Gradle. In my case, reverted to 7.4.2 and this sorted my issue. Also for an ionic project.

Comment: This is still happening. Its been a few months now.

Comment: When I first encountered this issue I have simply downgraded Gradle back to 7.4.2 but now I needed to make AGP 8.1 wokring to get the automatic language creating feature https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#locale-names so I went through every single build.gradle file in the project root and migrated applicationId to namespace and finally I was able to build!

Comment: How to set a namespace for a dependent Flutter plugin that is referenced through YAML dependencies?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This error occurs after **Android Gradle Plugin** updated >= 8.x.x. To get rid of error use following method:

1. Open your flutter project's Android folder via Android Studio
2. Use [AGP Upgrade Assistant](https://developer.android.com/build/agp-upgrade-assistant) to update gradle version. To do that, if your project's gradle version is 7.x.x just wait. When building gradle file finish, you will some popup in the bottom-right corner of screen.
   [image]
3. Click start AGP Upgrade Assistant and process upgrading.
4. After upgrade process finished, update your top-level gradle file like following.:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    // This code is where all the magic happens and fixes the error.
    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
                project.android {
                    if (namespace == null) {
                        namespace project.group
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // This code is where all the magic happens and fixes the error.
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

5. Rebuild and it should be working. If it is not working go File > Invalidate Caches and restart Android studio. After these process, you should be able to run your flutter android app without problem!

**What was the problem?**

Problem is about namespace. Earlier versions of gradle, they removed namespace from AndroidManifest.xml and transfer to gradle file. Even your project's namespace is transferred to new system, some flutter plugins may not be updated to recent gradle versions.

**SOLUTION**

To fix that, we are adding following code into top-level gradle file for adding namespace its sub-projects (plugins) via gradle.

```
  subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
            project.android {
                if (namespace == null) {
                    namespace project.group
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recognized this answer is for kotlin, so, how to edit correct in `build.gradle.kts` version? would you mind to add for `kts` version?

Comment: works for react-native projects as well, after running the AGP Upgrade Assistant

Answer (score 15):

This is a known issue.

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/6504

If you are using capacitor 4, do not upgrade to gradle 8.

Comment: I'm with a FLutter project, so no Capacitor, but have the error. I have the namespace specified in the build.gradle.

Comment: That's exactly my case. downgraded to 7.4.2 and the error is gone

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I had to open each capacitor plugins in Android Studio, then check the "AndroidManifest.xml" for each of them, and copy the package name to the related "build.gradle" using "namespace".

1. Go to each capacitor plugins, and find the package name from the `AndroidManifest.xml`:
   [image: first step to find the package name]
2. Open the related `build.gradle` and add the `namespace`:
   [image: second step to enter the package name in the build.gradle file]

Answer (score 6):

You can resolve the namespace issue after updating to AGP 8.+ by adding the following script in the android/build.gradle file:

```
subprojects {
   afterEvaluate { project ->
       if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
           project.android {
               if (namespace == null) {
                   namespace project.group
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your build.gradle you can conditionally set the namespace using the following:

```
android {
     ...
     if (project.android.hasProperty("namespace")) {
         namespace("change.this.to.your.namespace")
     }
```

This detects if the project has the property namespace requirement, and if so sets it.

Comment: This fixed it for me with Gradle 8.3.0

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I accidentally close the android studio while it was loading.

I closed the android studio and ran the following:

```
npx cap sync android
npx jetify
```

Than I opened my android studio and it loaded it's things and all worked fine again!

Answer (score 2):

Tested and it worked,

No need downgrade build gradle to `7.x.x` version,

Since after set this suitable `build gradle version`,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.3'
```

Then, set both `namespace`  and `testNamespace` value

```
android {
compileSdk 34

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
namespace = "mobile.template"
testNamespace = "mobile.template.free"
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).

    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

[image]

Comment: If sub-module is included in project, build.gradle of sub-module has to be changed as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify namespace in your *build.gradle (Module:app)* by adding this  line in your defaultConfig block `namespace("com.example.app")`

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"

    //Add this line 
    namespace("com.example.app")

    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    android.buildFeatures.buildConfig true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the answers above. I developed something dynamic. Because the problem is with the new version of Gradle, the >= 8.0.0. So if you want it to be compatible with older versions and compatible with the new ones do this:

```
android {
    if (getGradle().getGradleVersion().substring(0, 1).toInteger() >= 8) {
        namespace "com.something.plugin"
    }
    compileSdkVersion project.hasProperty('compileSdkVersion') ? rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion : 29
    defaultConfig {
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `flutter` and this problem appeared when upgraded my app via `AGP` to gradle version 8.0. Then using `AGP` to raise or lower the `gradle` version did not work due to the same error `namespace not specified`. In the place where the error is reported, it also indicates the name of the package that is causing this problem, I had this `fluttertoast`. Removed this package from the project, it is not very important for me and the error went away, AGP worked again

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':fluttertoast'.
```

Also make sure that the namespace is indicated at the very beginning of the android manifest  `AndroidManifest.xml`. I created my project through the console and the `skeleton template`, there was no namespace

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="you.package.name.here">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    //Add this line
    namespace("com.google.example.maps.roadsapi")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.example.maps.roadsapi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
    
this worked namespace("com.example.app")
```

in order to start updating gradle source file downloads... i'm sure there are other issues since I'm upgrading an older studio project from 9 years ago...

Had earlier upgraded

```
 //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue go to **build.gradle** file in project

- Remove applicationId.
- Add namespace filedf with value.
- Add testNamespace with value.

Comment: add additional code for clarity and reference

Comment: Does the namespace replace the applicationId?

Comment: There's an even easier way of resolving this problem.  Check my answer : )

Answer (score 0):

Add : namespace 'your package (com.example.projectname)' into android{
} of your build.gradle and sync

Answer (score 0):

Check if each local module(lib) has completed the namespace upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error after I attempted to upgrade to capacitor 5 from capacitor 4. It turns out that I was getting this error because some of my capacitor plugins did not migrate successfully to version 5.

The fix I implemented:

1. Check on your package.json that every capacitor plugin is up to date
2. npm i or yarn install
3. npx cap sync android

Answer (score 0):

The AGP Upgrade Assistant does'n show all the information.

You have to upgrade all the Flutter plugin to Gradle 8 before you upgrade you app project.

- Use `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files` in your app project.
- In the `Sync` result window, check every failed item to find which plugin doesn't have the namespace.
- Upgrade the plugin to new version, or ask the author to upgrade it to Gradle 8.
- repeat until all the plugin has been upgraded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a new style of build.gradle file with the upgrade to 8.0.0

An example of the new style can be seen below:

```css
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.firstname_lastname"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.firstname_lastname"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

You can request that Android Studio produces this new version of the build.gradle file by keeping the 8.0.0 tool setting and doing:

File --> New Flutter Project

Then name the project firstname_lastname

Now go to the new project's build.gradle file and it's all done for you.

With the new style of build.gradle file, you can overcome this error easily.

All you need to do is, make a copy of your main project's current build.gradle file and then copy/paste the new build.gradle file to replace it.

After pasting the newer version of the build.gradle file, add the vital differences relying on the copy you made of what was.

This should resolve the problem by giving you an updated build.gradle file which conforms with the requirements of upgrade 8.0.0

Happy Coding : )

And don't forget to salute this answer.

Comment: I tried it after writing it and it doesn't work as I planned.  But a few steps closer hopefully.

Comment: In my case, it seems that the underlying problem is a clash between the Kotlin version I call in my build.gradle file and the Kotlin which runs Android Studio via its plugins.  Android Studio technology is moving forwards but the plugin I am using is holding AS back so to speak.  Reviews at plugins.jetbrains.com suggest I must be very careful with my choice of upgrade version.  Currently I am version 1.7 but calling on version 1.9+

Comment: It turns out that in order to get a new version of Kotlin for Android Studio, you can wait for the AS team to offer an upgrade, or you can download a newer edition of Android Studio.  It occurs to me that what I've come across is an Android Studio dead end - a fault that couldn't be designed around.  Get your new edition too [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).

Answer (score -3):

I modified gradle script as follows:

```
android {
       
buildFeatures {
    
    aidl true

    buildConfig true
}
...
}
```