# Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file Flutter Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

Suddenly I'm getting the namespace error in my flutter project.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.ApplicationVariantImpl.
> > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

```
    If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.
enter code here
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Yeah, the screenshot has nothing to do with the error. Have you upgraded Gradle recently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix 'namespace not specified' error in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76108428/how-do-i-fix-namespace-not-specified-error-in-android-studio)

Comment: @TheLibrarian Yes I have update the Gradle

Comment: Add your package name in the build.gradle (app) file as `namespace package-name`  in android block.

Comment: Duplicate question of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76108428/how-do-i-fix-namespace-not-specified-error-in-android-studio/77738936 Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76108428/how-do-i-fix-namespace-not-specified-error-in-android-studio/77738936#77738936

Answer (score 1):

Read what the error tells you.

In newer versions of AGP, the declaration of namespace/package was moved from AndroidManifest and to build script.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    <!-- package="com.example.app" POOF! -->
>
```

and

```
android {
    namespace = "com.example.app"
```

Comment: I already did that, but still it shows that error

Comment: @Yogendra same with me, any updates ?

Comment: @AhmedElhenidy yeah, for me I couldn't upgrade my packages, and this error is being thrown for packages which are old, so I had to downgrade the AGP/Gradle version to v5.4.1

Comment: the main idea is that I have to upgrade my gradle version. any way, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
compileOptions
{
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlinOptions
{
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

Upgrade the Java version to 17 in the app-level build.gradle file. This adjustment should resolve the issue in my scenario.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zRn6.png