# How to fix 'Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.' with React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-development

Error

```
Execution failed for task ':appcenter-analytics:processDebugManifest'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessLibraryManifest$ProcessLibWorkAction
   > Incorrect package="com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.analytics" found in source AndroidManifest.xml.
     Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
     Recommendation: remove package="com.microsoft.appcenter.reactnative.analytics" from the source AndroidManifest.xml.
```

I am getting this error when trying to run an android React Native application, after upgrading the AGP with the AGP upgrade assistant (in Android Studio) from 7.4.2 to 8.2.1 (& Gradle version 8.2).

I have already specified a namespace it my own build.gradle (app) file:

```
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    compileSdkVersion 34
    namespace "com.example"
...
```

But as seen from the error, the issue is from a subproject dependency. There seems to be many (>10) of these dependencies with this issue. Which I think stems from them not specifying a namespace.

I have followed the advice from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77738936/23282142 on a similar post, which attempts to add a namespace to all the subprojects if they don't already have one. But it has not fixed the problem. Here is my top-level build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
        playServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1"
    }
    
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.1')
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

// From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76108428/how-do-i-fix-namespace-not-specified-error-in-android-studio
allprojects {
    // This code is where all the magic happens and fixes the error.
    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
                project.android {
                    if (namespace == null) {
                        namespace project.group
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // This code is where all the magic happens and fixes the error.
}
```