adding flutterblue package
I want to build an app that uses bluetooth. I read to add "flutterblue:" in the pubspec.yaml file under the "dependencies" section. But when I add this line, run "flutter pub get" in the terminal and try to run the app on the emulator or a real phone I get the following error:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_blue'.  
Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.  
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file.  
See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace. If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file.  Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.

Does somebody know what went wrong here ?
I expected to not get an error as I only added the package. I did not write a line of code that uses the package yet. I created a new flutter project and tried to run a simple "hello world" code and added the same "flutter_blue" line in the pubspec.yaml file. But I got the same error again

The error message not only specifies a specific problem, it also tells you where to find a possible solution. What didn't you understand?

You can try the solution mentioned in the stack overflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77738936/11775255

Flutter Blue has not seen updates in over three years, it should be considered deprecated. The team over at Flutter Blue Plus has forked the package and continued development. It is recommended to use flutter_blue_plus.
The issue you are seeing here is related to changes in the Gradle Build System which requires a new property called namespace.  This namespace property is discussed on the Android Docs.
